# Postgres regex not matching comma as expected

Tags: json, regex, postgresql

I have a text field containing JSON and I need to replace and eliminate some fields.  Below is an example of the JSON format.  I would like to remove certain fields suffixed by '-op' and the trailing comma but the comma is not being picked up for some reason.

```
{
    "miscId":[],
    "otherActivityData":{"activityDate-op":"eq","activityDate":"11/28/2017"}
}
```

I worked with a nice online tools to show my pattern should work for most languages =>  [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/)

The pattern is:

```
"activityDate-op":".+?",?
```

It picks everything up except the comma.  I did a regexp_match and the printed it out via raise notice and it produced

```
{"\"activityDate-op\":\"eq\""}
```

Can anyone help point out how I can pick up the comma?

Sometimes the field-op is last in the array so I need to have the 0 or 1 question mark quantifier in place.  If I remove the ? then it picks the comma up sometimes but also causes issues.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use regex, postgresql has extensive json functions which would help you parse & modify your json column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex. There is an [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to remove an element from a JSONB based on the element's path:

```
select j #- array['otherActivityData', 'activityDate-op']
from (
  values ( '{"miscId":[],
              "otherActivityData":{"activityDate-op":"eq","activityDate":"11/28/2017"}
            }'::jsonb) 
) as t(j);
```

returns:

```
{"miscId": [], "otherActivityData": {"activityDate": "11/28/2017"}}
```